# Linux Kernel v.5. linux/wait.h WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

Is there any function like *interruptible_sleep_on()* in kernel v5?
I found only *poll_wait()* for polling file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [linux 3.5 source code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.5/source/include/linux/wait.h#L577), we can see that those functions were deprecated. Look at the comments above their declaration:

```c
/*  
 * These are the old interfaces to sleep waiting for an event.  
 * They are racy.  DO NOT use them, use the wait_event* interfaces above.  
 * We plan to remove these interfaces.  
 */  
extern void sleep_on(wait_queue_head_t *q);  
extern long sleep_on_timeout(wait_queue_head_t *q,  
                      signed long timeout);  
extern void interruptible_sleep_on(wait_queue_head_t *q);  
extern long interruptible_sleep_on_timeout(wait_queue_head_t *q,  
                       signed long timeout);
```

The function to use instead are: *wait_event_killable()*, *wait_event_timeout()*, ...